# How to use paypal authentication signaure and timestamp in refund call

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to refund payment to a customer on behalf of a third party. I have studied permission APIs how to get access token and verification code to use it in authentication API to generate signature and timestamp. But after this i am still confused as to how to use this in Refund API. Currently this is my refund paypal code

```
CallerServices caller = new CallerServices();
APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
if(Configuration.getProperty("PaypalEnvironment").equals("sandbox"))
{
profile.setAPIUsername(Configuration.getProperty("PaypalAPIUsername"));
profile.setAPIPassword(Configuration.getProperty("PaypalAPIPassword"));
profile.setSignature(Configuration.getProperty("PaypalSignature"));
profile.setEnvironment(Configuration.getProperty("PaypalEnvironment"));
caller.setAPIProfile(profile);
}
RefundTransactionRequestType pprequest = new RefundTransactionRequestType();
if ((amount != null && amount.length() > 0)
        && (refundType.equals("Partial"))) {
    BasicAmountType amtType = new BasicAmountType();
    amtType.set_value(amount);
    amtType.setCurrencyID(CurrencyCodeType.fromString(currencyCode));
    pprequest.setAmount(amtType);
}
pprequest.setVersion("63.0");
pprequest.setTransactionID(transactionId);
pprequest.setMemo(note);
pprequest.setRefundType(RefundType.fromString(refundType));
RefundTransactionResponseType ppresponse = (RefundTransactionResponseType) caller
            .call("RefundTransaction", pprequest);
```

In this code how do i embed the signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For refund it is simple. Once you get the request token and verification code that's it. You don't need to pass this to refund API. All you have to above is just add this line

```
            profile.setSubject(emailid);
```

and it then it gets refunded.